# AlarmManager on being cancelled immediately invokes pending intent

Tags: android, android-intent, service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

So I have a section of code that schedules an alarm as follows

```
public void scheduleAlarm(){
    Log.d("Scheduler","Alarm is being scheduled");
    Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmSettings.this, VolumeService.class);
    intent.putExtra("MODE", mode);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmSettings.this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Log.d("Alarm ID:", String.valueOf(id));
    Log.d("Time", "Time was set for today: " + String.valueOf(time));
    if(time < System.currentTimeMillis()){
        time += (DAY);
        Log.d("Time", "Time was set for tomorrow: " + String.valueOf(time));
    }
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pintent);
}
```

The service that is being called is as follows

```
public class VolumeService extends Service{

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //My Service code goes here and makes changes to some settings
    Log.d("Service", "settings have been changed");
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
 }


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

and finally the portion of code that is supposed to cancel the alarms (stay with me, I know its lengthy)

```
//Unschedule the alarm that is getting deleted
    Log.d("Unscheduler", "Alarm is being unscheduled");
    Intent uIntent = new Intent(AlarmSettings.this, VolumeService.class);
    PendingIntent uPintent = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmSettings.this, id, uIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager uAlarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    uAlarm.cancel(uPintent);
    uPintent.cancel();
```

Now, my problem is that when the user deletes an alarm and subsequently calls the unschedule portion of the code, the `volumeService` is immediately called and the settings are changed. However, this defeats the purpose of the user deleting the alarm as they will only delete it to prevent it from firing and changing the settings. I have checked everywhere imaginable over the course of weeks and am just beating my head against the wall. Now that I have posted it on here though, it will be that I have made a very simple mistake. In any case, thanks for the help in advance!

--edit #1--
Removed the line uPintent.cancel() in the unscheduler portion and still doesn't work.

Comment: Delete the `uPintent.cancel();` line and try it again.

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: just delete 
AlarmManager uAlarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    uAlarm.cancel(uPintent);

and try it again ..reply ASAP..I have other solution too .reply fast

Comment: Post a complete sample project that reproduces the problem. I have never seen this, and I have done a lot of work with `AlarmManager` over the years.